# FastAPI running on ECS and facing public with ALB returns Error: socket hang up although the ALB idle timeout is large enough

Tags: amazon-web-services, fastapi, amazon-ecs

I have a FastAPI app running on ECS, and the cluster faces the public with an ALB. ALB idle timeout is large enough (10 minutes), but when the server takes more than 1 minute to respond, I get the `socket hang up` in the postman.

I have tried to lower the ALB idle timeout to a low number (for example 15 seconds) and once the idle time reaches that number, I get a 504 Gateway timeout error. So, I think from that, I can conclude the error I am seeing is not related to ALB idle timeout.

Also, the app is working fine locally.

P.s: I tried to run the uvicorn with `--timeout-keep-alive 600` option but didn't work and still got the same error when the server took more than a minute.